# General topology on $R^n$

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Prove that set $X=\left\{(x,y)|x^2+(y-3)^2\le4\right\}\cap\left\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2\le2\right\}$ is compact and connected. I think it is compact because we have intersection of two closed balls and that should be closed and bounded. For connectedness i tried using definition, if there don't exist two open disjunctive sets such that $X=A\cup B$ then it is connected. But i cant go further, i know that the intersection of those two balls is not empty, but problem is that $X$ is not equal $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning compactness, I have nothing to add to what you wrote. And your set is the intersection of two disks; in particular, it is the intersection of two convex sets. In particular, it is convex. And every convex subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is path-connected and, in particular, it is connected.

Comment: Intersection of those two sets gives a point $(x,y)$ where $y\in (1,\sqrt{2})$ and x is in some range which must contain $\sqrt{2}$. Is this helpful?

Comment: I'm confused. Is there something incomplete in my answer?

Comment: I am not familiar with convex sets, so i am trying to solve this using only path conectedness and conectednees.

Comment: A subset $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is convex if, when $v,w\in V$, then the line segment that join them is a subset of $V$. It is clear that disks are convex, that the intersection of two convex sets is convex and that every convex set is path-connected.